# Input type text not taking values even after making it editable

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

Hi i have a requirement where i will be editing the fields when i click on a edit link.Initially the fields will be under disabled and readonly state.Oncei click on edit the value should be blank and editable.

My problem here is the value is changed to blank and i can even place my cursor in the text box.But it is not taking any values that i type.
Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style></style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function editEmail(){

    var demo = document.getElementById('email');

    demo.readonly = false;
    demo.disabled = false;
    demo.value=" ";

    return false;}

function editMob(){

    var demo = document.getElementById('mobile');

    demo.readonly = false;
    demo.disabled = false;
    demo.value=" ";

    return false;}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Edit profile</h3><h3>${userName}</h3>
    <form action="/ChangeProfile" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Email ID</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email"  name="emailId" value="${emailId}" disabled readonly></td>
            <td><label><a href="#email" id="Aemail" onclick="editEmail()">edit</a></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Mobile</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobileNO" value="${mobileNO}" disabled readonly /></td>
            <td><label><a href="#mobile" id="Amobile" onclick="editMob()">edit</a></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="confirm" value="Confirm" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly let me know if i missed anything in coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, the only mistake you are making is in writing `"readonly"` it should be in camelCase like this `readOnly`

Eg: `demo.readOnly = false;`

[**Here is a working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6b65sdjq/1/)

Comment: heyy yeaa it worked.verrry minute one,i couldnt get that .Thank you.You saved my time